# "Factorising" a presheaf on a product of category to a product of presheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given two small categories $A$ and $B$ and a presheaf $Z : (A \times B)^{op} \rightarrow Set$, I was wondering if there is a way to construct "minimal" presheaves $X : A^{op} \rightarrow Set$ and $Y : B^{op} \rightarrow Set$ such that there is a mono $Z \rightarrow X \times Y$ where $X\times Y : (a, b) \mapsto X(a) \times Y(b)$.

I can take $X := colim_{b \in B} Z(-,b)$ and $Y := colim_{a \in A} Z(a,-)$ but this is quite big. For example, if $Z$ is a representable, i.e. if $Z = A(-, a_0) \times B(-, b_0)$ for some $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$, taking the colimits give me much larger presheaves.

Comment: If you are asking this in a precise sense, that $(X,Y,Z \to X \times Y)$ should have a universal property, then the answer is "no".